# How to declare a variable for using it into multiple IF

Tags: vb.net, variables, variable-declaration

I would like to know what are relevant differences between declaring a variable one time (out of an If-then-else loop) or multiple times (into every case):

1st case (I'm using this way):

```
If A < 0 Then
    Dim YNC As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Select Yes-No-Cancel", vbYesNoCancel, "Select")
    'Some code
ElseIf A = 0 Then
    Dim YNC As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Select Yes-No-Cancel", vbYesNoCancel, "Select")
    'Some code
Else
    Dim YNC As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Select Yes-No-Cancel", vbYesNoCancel, "Select")
    'Some code
End If
```

2nd case:

```
Dim YNC As MsgBoxResult
If A < 0 Then
    YNC = MsgBox("Select Yes-No-Cancel", vbYesNoCancel, "Select")
    'Some code
ElseIf A = 0 Then
    YNC = MsgBox("Select Yes-No-Cancel", vbYesNoCancel, "Select")
    'Some code
Else
    YNC = MsgBox("Select Yes-No-Cancel", vbYesNoCancel, "Select")
    'Some code
End If
```

Is there any reason to change my code?

Have I done the correct choice?

**EDIT**

I prefer the 1st because it's more readable (at least for me)

**EDIT 2**

Ok i think i get my answer into the link posted by Steve:

> Minimizing Scope
>
> In general, when declaring any variable or constant, it is good
>   programming practice to make the scope as narrow as possible (block
>   scope is the narrowest). This helps conserve memory and minimizes the
>   chances of your code erroneously referring to the wrong variable.
>   Similarly, you should declare a variable to be Static (Visual Basic)
>   only when it is necessary to preserve its value between procedure
>   calls.

Comment: Do you want to use that YNC after the if ends? I suppose yes right? Then try to declare it multiple times inside the ifs. [Scopes in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx)

Comment: @Steve It's possible. I have multiple msgbox questions. Thanks for the link, but I know scopes limit. My question is: what is better and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether you need to use that value further down to control program flow.

If you need the value again you have no choice but to declare it first, otherwise it will be out of scope.

The difference in terms of "resources" is so minimal (if any) that it is not worth worrying about.

Comment: In terms of readability and code quality it _is_ worth worrying about

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the variable will be generated anyhow, If you consider the better readability of code, Case 2 would be good.

This leads to the scope of variable after IF too, so you can use it after IF also..

According to me, CASE 2 would be better for developer (as it not affect system & provide better code readability & understandability  for further changes).

Answer (score 0):

The difference appear after your posted code.

```
If A < 0 Then
    Dim YNC As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Select Yes-No-Cancel", vbYesNoCancel, "Select")
    'Some code
ElseIf A = 0 Then
    Dim YNC As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Select Yes-No-Cancel", vbYesNoCancel, "Select")
    'Some code
Else
    Dim YNC As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Select Yes-No-Cancel", vbYesNoCancel, "Select")
    'Some code
End If

' YNC doesn't exists here
```

.

```
Dim YNC As MsgBoxResult
If A < 0 Then
    YNC = MsgBox("Select Yes-No-Cancel", vbYesNoCancel, "Select")
    'Some code
ElseIf A = 0 Then
    YNC = MsgBox("Select Yes-No-Cancel", vbYesNoCancel, "Select")
    'Some code
Else
    YNC = MsgBox("Select Yes-No-Cancel", vbYesNoCancel, "Select")
    'Some code
End If

' YNC does exists and you can use it
```